# BigQuery split column and get count of count each substring

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In BigQuery I would like to create a query to count the occurrence of words in a comments field and group by a count of each occurrence. This would me get a sense of what words were used more than others and get a sense of user behavior and moods. Pretty new to bigquery so any ideas will be helpful.

Comment: the main idea here - is to try something first by yourself and if any particular/specific issues  - present to us and we will be happy to help. So, what have you tried so far? Any query? Have you tried to search for similar or exact question?

Comment: ah yes I don't have write rights yet...was looking at mysql which i do have access to but it seems it relies on substring so i think i would have to do a count of delimiter first and then get N occurrences...think I can use explode(split(field,' ') as word to get each word separated. hopefully I'll get write rights soon. thanks

Comment: i lost - are you working with mysql or bigquery?! you don't need to have write rights to play and run simple query :o) so you can start

Comment: Bigquery. Yeah my bad I am going to set up with the free account somehow forgot that option using another account now.

Comment: I guess I didn't see that...it helped a lot. Considering I realized that we weren't using Leqacy sql which is what my solution depends on.

Answer (score -1):

What I ended up doing was using the split function...

```
SELECT 
COUNT(JJ) AS STUFF, JJ
FROM
(SELECT SPLIT(text, ' ') AS JJ FROM [bigquery-public-
data:hacker_news.comments] LIMIT 1000 ) 
GROUP BY JJ
ORDER BY STUFF DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Obviously it can be manipulated more by using replace to remove other characters before splitting.